# Escaping end of line with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

This time I'm trying to parse a text file into `[[String]]` using Parsec. Result is a list consisting of lists that represent lines of the file. Every line is a list that contains words which may be separated by any number of spaces, (optionally) commas, and spaces after commas as well.

Here is my code and it even works.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (spaces)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import System.IO
import System.Environment

myParser :: Parser [[String]]
myParser =
    do x <- sepBy parseColl eol
       eof
       return x

eol :: Parser String
eol = try (string "\n\r")
  <|> try (string "\r\n")
  <|> string "\n"
  <|> string "\r"
  <?> "end of line"

spaces :: Parser ()
spaces = skipMany (char ' ') >> return ()

parseColl :: Parser [String]
parseColl = many parseItem

parseItem :: Parser String
parseItem =
    do optional spaces
       x <- many1 (noneOf " ,\n\r")
       optional spaces
       optional (char ',')
       return x

parseText :: String -> String
parseText str =
    case parse myParser "" str of
      Left e  -> "parser error: " ++ show e
      Right x -> show x

main :: IO ()
main =
    do fileName <- head <$> getArgs
       handle <- openFile fileName ReadMode
       contents <- hGetContents handle
       putStr $ parseText contents
       hClose handle
```

Test file:

> this is my test file
>   this, line, is, separated, by, commas
>   and this is another, line

Result:

```
[["this","is","my","test","file"],
 ["this","line","is","separated","by","commas"],
 ["and","this","is","another","line"],
 []] -- well, this is a bit unexpected, but I can filter things
```

Now, to make my life harder, I wish to be able to 'escape' `eol` if there is a comma `,` before it, even if the comma is followed by spaces. So this is should be considered one line:

> this is, *spaces may be here*
>   my line

What is best strategy (most idiomatic and elegant) to implement this syntax (without losing the ability to ignore commas inside a line).

Comment: Parsec is great, but for something this simple, why not use `lines` and `words`, then run the output through something that removes leading and trailing commas, then filters blank lines?  Sometimes full parsing is necessary, but for something so simple, it looks like overkill to me.

Comment: @jamshidh, you're right, but this is not a real program. It is simplified example. In my real program I cannot get away with `lines` and `words`...

Comment: Doesn't parsec have eof defined?
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:eof

Comment: @Arnon, yes it does and I use it.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry! I didn't notice it hiding there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of solutions come to mind....  One is easy, the other is medium difficulty.

---

The medium-difficulty solution is to define an itemSeparator to be a comma followed by whitespace, and a lineSeparator to be a '\n' or '\r' followed by whitespace....  Make sure to skip non '\n', '\r'-whitespace, but no further, at the end of the item parse, so that the very next char after an item must be either a '\n', '\r', or ',', which determines, without backtracking, whether a new item or line is coming.

Then use `sepBy1` to define `parseLine` (ie- parseLine = parseItem `sepBy1` parseItemSeparator), and endBy to define parseFile (ie- parseFile = parseLine `endBy` parseLineSeparator).

You really do need that `sepBy1` on the inside, vs `sepBy`, else you will have a list of zero sized items, which causes an infinite loop at parse time.  `endBy` works like `sepBy`, but allows extra '\n', '\r' at the end of the file....

---

An easier way would be to canonicalize the input by running it though a simple transformation before parsing.  You can write a function to remove whitespace after a comma (using `dropWhile` and `isSpace`), and perhaps even simplify the different cases of '\n', '\r'....  then run the output through a simplified parser.

Something like this would do the trick (this is untested....)

```
canonicalize::String->String
canonicalize [] == []
canonicalize (',':rest) = ',':canonicalize (dropWhile isSpace rest)
canonicalize ('\n':rest) = '\n':canonicalize (dropWhile isSpace rest)
canonicalize ('\r':rest) = '\n':canonicalize (dropWhile isSpace rest) --all '\r' will become '\n'
canonicalize (c:rest) = c:canonicalize rest
```

Because Haskell is lazy, this transformation will work on streaming data as the data comes in, so this really won't slow anything down at all (depending on how much you simplify the parser, it could even speed things up....  Although most likely it will be close to a wash)

I don't know how complicated the full question is, but perhaps a few rules added to a canonicalization function will in fact allow you to use `lines` and `words` after all....

Comment: Solution involving transformation before parsing is not acceptable, because parsec's reports about position of parsing error will become inaccurate (in my real program it is important info, sorry). Another solution is also unacceptable, because items in a line can be separated these ways: `item,item`, `item  item`, `item  ,  item`. At the end of a line there *may* be spaces, there may be none of them as well.

Comment: Soln 1 does allow zero or more spaces at the end of a line....  I did miss the case items being separated by no comma, but you should be able to easily account for that using `optional`.  You are correct about the position becoming inaccurate for the second solution, if that is important use the modified version of number one (with `optional`)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `optional spaces` in `parseColl`, like this:

```
parseColl :: Parser [String]
parseColl = optional spaces >> many parseItem

parseItem :: Parser String
parseItem =
    do 
       x <- many1 (noneOf " ,\n\r")
       optional spaces
       optional (char ',')
       return x
```

Second, divide separator from item

```
parseColl :: Parser [String]
parseColl = do
      optional spaces
      items <- parseItem `sepBy` parseSeparator
      optional spaces
      return items

parseItem :: Parser String
parseItem = many1 $ noneOf " ,\n\r"

parseSeparator = try (optional spaces >> char ',' >> optional spaces) <|> spaces
```

Third, we recreate a bit `eol` and `spaces`:

```
eol :: Parser String
eol = try (string "\n\r")
  <|> string "\r\n"
  <|> string "\n"
  <|> string "\r"
  <|> eof
  <?> "end of line"

spaces :: Parser ()
spaces = skipMany1 $ char ' '

parseColl :: Parser [String]
parseColl = do
      optional spaces
      items <- parseItem `sepBy` parseSeparator
      optional spaces
      eol
      return items
```

Finally, let's rewrite `myParser`:

```
myParser = many parseColl
```